# How to use a scaling matrix

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have a matrix I create with this code:

```
    screenscalex = (float)_graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 1920f;
    screenscaley = (float)_graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 1920f;
    ScalingFactor = new Vector3(screenscalex, screenscaley, 1);
    Global.SpriteScale = Matrix.CreateScale(ScalingFactor);
```

But I can't figure out how to use the matrix to scale down my sprites this is the code I'm currently using to scale them down:

```
    batch.End();
    batch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate,null, null, null, null, null, Global.SpriteScale);
    //This is where the background gets drawn
    backgroundsprite = new Sprite(background, Vector2.Zero);
    backgroundsprite.Draw(batch);
    //ive tried this too below
    //batch.Draw(background, new Rectangle(0, 0, graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth, graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight), Color.White);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example Microsoft provides for scaling sprites, they are using an overload for the SpriteBatch.Draw method which accepts a scale parameter of type Single.

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
  ...
  // Initialize the batch with the scaling matrix
  spriteBatch.Begin();
  // Draw a sprite at each corner
  for (int i = 0; i < spritepos.Length; i++)
  {
      spriteBatch.Draw(square, spritepos[i], null, Color.White,
          rotation, origin, scale, SpriteEffects.None, depth);
  }
  spriteBatch.End();
  base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

[Scaling Sprites Based On Screen Size (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447674.aspx)

[SpriteBatch.Draw Method (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw.aspx)

Comment: And in this case what would scale be

Comment: Their example uses a method quite similar to yours for determining the scale value, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: So is scale(in your code) equivalent to ScalingFactor in my code?

Comment: Actually, I believe you should be able to provide the `screenscale` value based on the width as your scale. Apologies that I can't provide a better example, I don't have access to any of my older XNA source code.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to come up a lot. I wrote a quick tutorial on my blog a little while ago with an explanation.

http://www.craftworkgames.com/blog/monogame-code-snippets/monogame-resolution-independence/

The most important bit of code is the scaling matrix, much like what you have already created in your question.

```
var scaleX = (float)GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / (float)VirtualScreenWidth;
var scaleY = (float)GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / (float)VirtualScreenHeight;

_screenScale = new Vector3(scaleX, scaleY, 1.0f);     

var scaleMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(_screenScale);

_spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, null, null, scaleMatrix);
// your drawing code here
_spriteBatch.End();
```

However, that's not the whole story so I recommend reading the full tutorial.